# RewriteCond REQUEST_URI not match whole path

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, server-variables

I am quite puzzled.

My goal is to detect, whether redirect is needed (path changed). This is a minimal example.

```
RewriteRule ^first$ second

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/$1$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```

And I am requesting `example.com/first` with intention to get `301 to second`.

Problem is, that the RewriteCond always evaluates to true and creates a loop.
On the first go, it is fine. But on the second request, which is now `example.com/second`, it evaluates to true again, even though `%{REQUEST_URI}` is `/second` and `$1` is `second`. I know it is.. I checked by redirecting to URL with both variables appended.

Any idea what am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please remember 2 important facts here:

1. `mod_rewrite` rules are run in a loop and it stops only when there is no successful rule execution
2. Value of `%{REQUEST_URI}` changes after rewrite or redirect.

Looking at your rules your 2nd redirect rule is faulty since you cannot use `%1` or `$1` in value part of `RewriteCond` thus making it always return true due to negation.

Comment: Alright, the fact that CondPattern cannot include backreferences was the culprit. Other than that %{REQUEST_URI} changes only on external redirect. If you just change the url without [R] flag, the variable stays the same

Comment: `REQUEST_URI` does change without `R` as well. That's the reason `THE_REQUST` is used in many rules to avoid looping.

Comment: Not sure in which instances then. I tried Rewriting (without extenal redirect) and the following rule `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /p=$1&u=%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]`, showed `p` different from `u`. `p` was the rewrited url from first rule and `u` was the original request url